# Usage of "of" in a strange way

Tags: meaning

> I scrape ice of the car

Can we use 'from' instead of 'of' if yes, why is 'of' preferred here?

Comment: "of" is just a typo. It should have been "off" instead

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a typo of *of* instead of *off*.

Comment: I dont know how to close a question, you can tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You can scrape the ice **from** the car, never **of** the car (the ice doesn't belong to the car). You can however scrape the ice **off** the car.

Answer (score 0):

This phrase is not idiomatic. You [scrape something *off*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scrape+off) something else; and *from* works as well but is used less often – see this [Google Ngram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scrape+ice+*&year_start=1920&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cscrape%20ice%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bscrape%20ice%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bscrape%20ice%20from%3B%2Cc0).

[image]

Comment: They are also semantically different. "from" implies that that car has ice *inside*

Comment: I disagree. "Off" excludes the idea that the ice may be inside the car but "from" doesn't imply that it is, just that it could be.